# equation of the line that passes through the point of intersection of the lines $3x-4y+1=0$ and $5x+y-1=0$ and cuts same length from both the axes.

Tags: coordinate-systems

Find the equation of the line that passes through the point of intersection of the lines $3x-4y+1=0$  and $5x+y-1=0$ and cuts the same length from both the axes.
$\bf{Try:} $
Since the line cuts the same length from both the axes, let the equation of the line be $\frac xa +\frac ya=1$.
The given two lines intersect at the point $\left(\frac 3{23},\frac 8{23}\right)$. Putting this point in the above equation we get $a =\frac {11} {23}$. Hence the equation of the line becomes $23x +23y=11$. But it has two given answers $23x +23y=11$ and $23x-23y+5=0$. I'm unable to find how the second equation comes and why.
Please give reason and describe. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the two lines -
\begin{gather*}
L_{1} :\frac{x}{a} +\frac{y}{a} =1\\
L_{2} :\frac{x}{a} -\frac{y}{a} =1
\end{gather*}
L1 intersects the axes at $(a,0)$ and $(0,a)$.
What is the distance between these two points, using the distance formula? This is the intercept of L1.

L2 intersects the axes at $(a,0)$ and $(0,-a)$. What is the distance between these two points? This is the intercept of L2.

Notice anything strange?

> Both the intercepts turn out to be equal, by the distance formula!

Using this fact, can you redo your problem so you get both the correct answers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the intercept?

Comment: @Loobear23 The distance between the points of intersection of the line and (in this case) the axes.

Comment: Oh right, I’ve just never seen the word intercept used in that way.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Then I can also consider the line $\frac x{-a} +\frac y{-a} =1$ isn't it?

Comment: @Math-Learner Yes, of course you can. There's one more case you need to consider, can you spot it? However, I believe that after solving all four equations, you will get two exactly same line. That leaves you with only 2 distinct solutions.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Yes I have got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The required line is $$(3x-4y+1)+t(5x+y-1)=0 \implies (3+5t)x+(-4+t)y+(1-t)=0~~~~(1)$$
Its cut on $x$-axis is $A=\frac{t-1}{3+5t}$ and on $y$ axis it is $B=\frac{t-1}{t-4}.$
$A=B \implies t=-7/4$, we get the Eq. of line from (1) as
$$x+y=11/23$$

**EDIT: $|A|=|B|$**
the other equation shuld be $A=-B \implies 3+5t=-(t-4) \implies t=1/6$ this choice gives $$x-y=-5/23$$

Comment: This is not the answer of my query. I've already found what you have written.

Comment: @Math-Learner See I justified the other answer, in my edit.

Comment: you have also given a nice approach (+1).